Can/Have there be(en) bullshit or non-sensical philosophical schools or traditions established in academia?
Taking 'bullshit' as by H. G. Frankfurt, of course. The question is essentially about professionalization and institutionalization in academic philosophy:
Is there any example of a philosophical school or tradition establishing itself in academia while producing mostly, or even only, incoherent, non-sensical works (either by accident or deliberately)?
Related: If there are no examples, is it possible, even in principle, to happen (considering present conditions of professionalization and institutionalization)?
edit: the question comes from reading Sokal & Bricmont's "Intellectual Impostures", which doesn't directly make a case for its covered authors, and reading about Boghossian, Lindsay and Pluckrose's "Grievance studies affair"

People on the American 'right' nowadays fashionably assert that everything that came out of France in particular and Europe in general is BS. Jordan Peterson is a cardinal example of this.  [I suspect JP doesnt speak French] People on the left prioritize feelings over objective reality. Which among other things involves throwing out almost all traditional education including classical philosophy. This results

@user66697 insofar as the methods of analytic philosophy are concerned, it is certainly not bullshit in this sense; apart from that, i recall reading something about daniel dennett calling on 'analytic metaphysics'

@DikranMarsupial yes, i'm aware of sokal, especially of sokal & bricmont's book, and also of the case of p boghossian, j lindsay and h pluckrose

@DikranMarsupial sophists were great bullshiters when they wanted, but they also helped establish critical thinking and what followed..

@DikranMarsupial I am not a Boris Johnson fan, but democratic societies need citizens able to think critically and argue so I will not agree with your conclusion.

@DikranMarsupial critical thinking has value both for discovering truth and for creating new possibilities . Arguing both sides of a position is an important epistemological method to critically examine claims, even if sometimes it is done on demand or as a game.

@DikranMarsupial it is good that you leave it there because it borders on prohibiting argumentation and free speech on the excuse that it is "rhetoric". I prefer rhetoric to exist even if can go overboard than eliminating it. Cheers

@DikranMarsupial "We shouldn't be taught rhetoric until AFTER we have learned to think critically and to value truth. The problem with teaching rhetoric and e.g. debating societies is the idea that it is about "winning" not "progess", and you should certainly not learn to argue either side of the argument (as sophists did).." those words of yours don't sound like appreciating rhetoric, argumentation and free speech, so it is good to illustrate to you your own points.

@DikranMarsupial doing you injustice is not my objective, however it is important to understand that argumentation (rhetoric in a sense) is necessary both for discovering truth and promoting critical thinking, cannot be separated. If one is claiming that argumentation has to be taught AFTER truth is valued, for example, this amounts to blindly accepting a dogma and not arguing for what truth is and thus discovering it. This is the  point made.

@DikranMarsupial the difference claimed between "rhetoric" and "argumentation" is a trivial one rather than meaningfully separating one from the other. One does rhetoric by arguing and arguing is itself a form of rhetoric ("persuasive speech").
